# Passing an object's hierarchy as an argument to it's parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Object called `html` inside a Function called `tpl()`.

```
html = {
    intro: ['intro', 'html'],
    common: { header: ['common', 'header', 'html'] },
    more:{ header: { link: ['hello', 'world'] } }
};
```

I am trying to access `html`'s values by passing it's hierarchy as an argument to `tpl()`;

I pass a String `common.header` as an argument, in order to get back the inner-object's content.

[example]:

```
var a = tpl('common.header'); // correct, returns 'common header html'
```

The issue, is when I need to target deeper nested objects:

```
var b = tpl('more.header.link'); // how can i make this work ?
```

---

This is the function I wrote, I am trying however to make it more *dynamic* (make it possible to work with deeper objects).

```
var tpl = function( path ){

  if(!path){ return false; }

  var that = this;

  that.html = {
    intro: ['intro', 'html'],
    common: { header: ['common', 'header', 'html'] },
    more: { header: { link: ['hello', 'world'] } }
  };

  path = path.split('.');

  return (!!path[1] ? that.html[path[0]][path[1]] : that.html[path[0]]).join('');

  /*
  // Here is where I am stuck
  for(var i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
    if( path[i][ path[i+1] ] ){}
  }
  */

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, how about keeping a pointer to the current substructure? Like this:

```
for(var tmp = that.html, i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
    tmp = tmp[path[i]];
    if (!tmp) return false;
}
return tmp;
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was trying to do!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var tpl = function( path ){

    if(!path){ return false; }

    var that = this;

    that.html = {
        intro: ['intro', 'html'],
        common: { header: ['common', 'header', 'html'],
                  footer: { text2: 'text2' } },
        more:{ header: { link: ['hello', 'world'] } }
    };

    path = path.split('.');

    var val = that.html;
    for(var i = 0; i < path.length; i++){
        val = val[path[i]];
    }
    return val;
};
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zkEKX/)**

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard question to answer, as i don't know what your future idea's for this function are. At the moment it looks to me as if you are literally over complicating the method in which you extract data from an object. For example,

```
var tpl = function( path ){

    if(!path){ return false; }

    var that = this;

    that.html = {
        intro: ['intro', 'html'],
        common: { header: ['common', 'header', 'html'] },
        more:{ header: { link: ['hello', 'world'] } }
    };

    return eval("that.html."+path);
};


console.log( tpl("common.header") );
```

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/8z4mC/

That will do what i think you want, however this code works exactly the same way when you think about it

```
html = {
    intro: ['intro', 'html'],
    common: { header: ['common', 'header', 'html'] },
    more:{ header: { link: ['hello', 'world'] } }
};


console.log( html.common.header );
```

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/jPLD5/

Maybe you need to explain future purpose for this for someone to make a better answer?

Comment: Thanks, but the pedant in me doesn't like using eval(). +1 for the working solution!

Answer (score 1):

I like @ori’ solution. Here's another, recursive option:

```
function resolvePath(object, path){
    if (!path || !path.length || path[0] === "") {
        return object;
    } else if (typeof path === 'string'){
        path = path.split('.');
    }
    var pathComponent = path.shift();
    if (pathComponent in object){
        return resolvePath(object[pathComponent], path);
    } else {
        throw new Error("Key does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers! I will add this one to my personal JS snippets :)